# Time-independent amplitude to go from one point to another in Feynman lectures (free particle)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, greens-functions, propagator

In the [third chapter](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_03.html) of [Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/) Volume III, I found this expression

> Suppose a particle with a definite energy is going in empty space from a location $\boldsymbol{r_1}$ to a location $\boldsymbol{r_2}$. In other words, it is a free particle with no forces on it. Except for a numerical factor in front, the amplitude to go from $\boldsymbol{r_1}$ to $\boldsymbol{r_2}$ is
> $$\langle\boldsymbol{r_2}|\boldsymbol{r_1}\rangle=\frac{e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}p r_{12}}}{r_{12}}.\tag{3.7}$$

Where, of course, $$\boldsymbol{r_{12}}=\boldsymbol{r_2}-\boldsymbol{r_1}$$ and he is talking about a *free particle*.
As for the scalar product $|\boldsymbol{r_1}\rangle$ and $|\boldsymbol{r_2}\rangle$ are understood to be computed at different times, so we're using Heisenberg picture (although Feynman never mentions it explicitly, at this point of the book he hasn't talked about operators yet).

This expression is later used in other chapters (e.g. eq. (10.10) in [chapter 10](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_10.html)) but I can't figure out how to derive this. It is somehow remiscent of the free particle propagator
$$K(x_1, t_1;x_2,t_2)=\left(\frac{m}{2i\pi(t_2-t_1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{i\frac{px-Et}{\hbar}}.$$

There are two differences:

- There is no time dependence in Feynman's formula;
- The $\frac{1}{r_{12}}$ factor.

While the former may be due to the fact that the particle has *definite energy*, so the time factor is not relevant, the latter is a total mistery to me? Does that fact just appear carrying out the calculations in 3 dimensions or is there something else I am not taking into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Feynman's expression $$ G({\bf r})~=~\langle {\bf r}_2 | {\bf r}_1 \rangle~=~\frac{\exp(ikr)}{r}\tag{3.7}$$ is the [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator)/[Greens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) $$(\nabla^2+k^2)G({\bf r})~=~-4\pi \delta^3({\bf r})$$
   for the 3D [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation)/the free [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation).
2. In this picture time $t$ has been replaced by its Fourier-transformed variable, the energy $E$. In fact Feynman states below eq. (3.7):

   > *For most of these initial discussions we will suppose that the source always emits the particles with a given energy so we will not need to worry about the time.*

Comment: This makes it clear. By the way, I noticed that the quote in my question (that you edited) was wrong. I checked FLP on Caltech website and in the italian edition there is a typo, i.e. the dot product $i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{r}$ in the exponent. The equation was also remiscent of the spherical monochromatic wave solution but that exponent got me.

Comment: Aha, a typo. That makes sense.